# Why is forecast option not appearing Quicksight chart?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

I am building a dashboard reading data from a Redshift data set. The issue appears on a sales graph. The forecast option is not appearing on the graph (see the picture). What may be the issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That might happens because ML Insights is only available on the Enterprise Edition of Amazon QuickSight. If you are using the Standard Edition, you can easily upgrade with a 1-click on the Manage QuickSight page.

The second thing you have to check is your Dataset

The data must have the following properties:

```
At least one metric (for example, sales, orders, shipped units, sign-ups, and so on).

At least one category dimension (for example, product category, channel, segment, industry, and so on). Categories with NULL values are ignored.

Anomaly detection requires a minimum of 15 data points for training. For example, if the grain of your data is daily, you need at least 15 days of data. If the grain is monthly, you need at least 15 months of data.
```

[Dataset Requirements for using ML Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/ml-data-set-requirements.html)